# How to remove http response header for specific pages?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, response-headers

I'd like to remove the "X-Frame-Options" response header for certain pages (or just change the value) so that those pages can be viewed from an iframe on anonymous sites.

I've tried

```
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
```

But not working.

Is it even possible?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/11/02/change-or-modify-a-response-header-value-using-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the domain that you expect to load your page in an iframe:

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "allow-from http://www.trustedsite.com");
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options